# AngularJS and underscore usage in same example

Tags: angularjs

i am leaning how to use underscore in AngularJS. i try to extract last 2 element from array and show in alert. code is working but the problem is last two element is showing together in alert but i want to show each element in alert one after one. here is my code. please tell me what i should use as a result each last 2 element in alter one after one.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('_', function() {
  return window._; //Underscore should be loaded on the page
});

myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, _) {
    $scope.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS2',
      'AngularJS1'
    ];

    var x = _.last($scope.awesomeThings, 2);
        //alert(x[0]);

        _.each([x],function(i)
    {
        alert(i);
    });

  });
```

**i also follow these links**

[how to break the _.each function in underscore.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779799/how-to-break-the-each-function-in-underscore-js)

[how to install underscore.js in my angular application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29768009/how-to-install-underscore-js-in-my-angular-application)

[Plucking an Object in an array using underscore.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31929651/plucking-an-object-in-an-array-using-underscore-js)

Comment: still got no answer.........waiting :(

Answer (score 1):

`_.last(..., 2)` will return an array containing 2 items for you.

```
var x = _.last($scope.awesomeThings, 2);
```

`_.each` loops through the array, so:

```
_.each([x], function(i) {
```

Notice how you wrapped `x` in *another* array, unnecessarily.
It successfully loops through the only item in the array, which is another array containing the data you needed.

Your solution should be as simple as:

```
_.each(x, function(i) {
  alert(i);
});
```

Or simpler, like you already noticed you can do:

```
_.each(x, alert);
```

Answer (score 0):

i found out the solution what i was looking for.

these two line solve my issue

```
var x = _.last($scope.awesomeThings, 2);
_.each(x.reverse(), alert);
```

### full code example

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('_', function() {
  return window._; //Underscore should be loaded on the page
});


myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, _) {
    $scope.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS2',
      'AngularJS1'
    ];
    //alert('pp');
    /*_.each([1,2,3],function(i)
    {
        alert(i);
    });*/
    var x = _.last($scope.awesomeThings, 2);
    _.each(x.reverse(), alert);
        //alert(x[0]);

        /*_.each([x],function(i)
    {
        alert(i);
    });*/

  });
```